# Switching between multiple reports (.rdlc) in a single report viewer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, rdlc

I have 2 reports, **"report1.rdlc"** and **"report2.rdlc"**. I want to be able to swap between them in a single report viewer (**"rv_1"**).

I also have 3 buttons:
**btn_1** which does:

```
rv_1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Application1.Report1.rdlc"
rv_1.RefreshReport()
```

**btn_2** which does:

```
rv_1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Application1.Report2.rdlc"
rv_1.RefreshReport()
```

**btn_3** which does:

```
dim rds as new ReportDataSource
rds.name = 
rds.value = 
rv_1.reset()
rv_1.LocalReport.DataSources.add(rds)
rv_1.RefreshReport()
```

No matter what I put for `rds.name` and `rds.value`, it leaves me with

> A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'dataSetName_TableName'.

What do I need to put there in order to get this to work correctly?

Comment: I know you're working in VB. But this is one of those areas which belongs to the framework etc, not the language - and it's case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub REPORT1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
   If CON.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then : 
     CON.Open() : 
   End If 
   CMD.Connection = CON 
   CMD.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM accounts" 
   DR = CMD.ExecuteReader 
   If DR.HasRows Then 
  Do While (DR.Read) 
    Me.DataSet1.TblData.AddTblDataRow(DR("FNAME"), DR("LNAME"), DR("MI")) 
  Loop 
 End If Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc" 
 Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport() 
End Sub
```

Comment: Private Sub REPORT1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        If CON.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then : CON.Open() : End If
        CMD.Connection = CON
        CMD.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM accounts"

        DR = CMD.ExecuteReader

        If DR.HasRows Then

            Do While (DR.Read)
                Me.DataSet1.TblData.AddTblDataRow(DR("FNAME"), DR("LNAME"), DR("MI"))
            Loop

        End If

        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc"
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

    End Sub

Comment: Please edit your answer with the above code rather than adding a comment.